# creating named instances of a class within a for loop -- related to networkx -- Python

Tags: python, networkx

The problem I am facing is following:

Suppose we have some class ( not important what it does):

```
class Node: ...
    ...
```

What I need now is creating several instances of this class; all with names.
I tried several things, here one try, which is obviously not working. just to make clear what I want to achieve:

```
for i in range(number_of_instances):
    "name"+str(i+1) = Node()
```

I need name for all of these objects to put them later on in a list. Actually it's the list containing all the nodes from a graph. The graph will be made with the **networkx** module. I need to be able to differentiate somehow between the nodes in the list. That's why I need the name.

```
my_graph = networkx.Graph()
for i in range(number_of_nodes):
    my_graph.add_node(Node(), name = str(i+1))
```

After executing this, `my_graph.nodes()` list somehow has mixed up the order of the nodes. So it does not correspond to order in which the nodes have been added to the graph.
So I don't know anymore how to exactly differentiate between the nodes.

**EDIT**

Given the laplacian for the graph I set everything up and then draw the graph.

```
name_dict = nx.get_node_attributes(my_graph, "name")
pos = nx.spring_layout(my_graph)
nx.draw(my_graph, pos, with_labels=False)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(my_graph, pos, name_dict)
plt.show()
```

However this does not result in the correct labeling.

Comment: Hello. While the use of ``globals()`` to do what you want is frowned upon by many people (I don't know why), I think you'll find the answer to your problem in this response of me here: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5036827/551449)

Comment: `Graph.node` (what `nodes()` returns) is a dictionary... which is implicitly unordered. You can get nodes by node attribute i.e. names though. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: After this I want to draw the graph. See **edit**  but the labels are not correct anymore..-.-

Comment: @eyquem: the *why* is that it generally makes your code more complex and harder to understand, and the use of globals makes your code harder to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a name, you only need a *reference*. One simple solution is to put the reference in a dictionary:

```
node = {}
for i in range(number_of_instances):
    node[i] = Node()
...
for i in range(number_of_nodes):
    my_graph.add_node(node[i], name="node %s" % i)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had troubles to label the reference and not the address where the Node-object is located. My code up there did not print the right reference to the right noe. I guess my code somehow was almost correct. Anyway it works now ^^